# Derived Class missing argument: 'self'

Tags: python, pygame

I need to incorporate derived classes into my game, but when I go to update the class it says

> TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

in trying to turn this (which works)

```
class Rain(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = 0
    def update(self):
        self.rect.bottom += 5

class BadRain(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = 0
    def update(self):
        self.rect.bottom += 5
```

into this which does not work

```
class Rain():
    def __init__(self,x,image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = 0

class Bad(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,image):
        Rain.__init__(self,x,image)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect.bottom += 5

class Good(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,image):
        Rain.__init__(self,x,image)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect.bottom += 5
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem

```
class Rain(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = 0

class Bad(Rain):
    def __init__(self,x,image):
        Rain.__init__(self,x,image)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect.bottom += 5

class Good(Rain):
    def __init__(self,x,image):
        Rain.__init__(self,x,image)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.bottom += 5
```

Comment: Why doesn't `Rain` call `Sprite.__init__` instead of all its subclasses doing it?